# jQuery Autocomplete Plugin 1.2.3 responsive width dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

Has anyone used this autocomplete plugin currently in github?   when you call the autocomplete function you can pass the width variable in pixels of the dropdown box, i.e. "width:200,".

I want the dropdown to be the same size as the input field.  This works fine when you know the width of the input field, but when using a responsive input field which changes width depending on the device your using, how would you go about setting this to the width of the current input field?

Answer (score 2):

I tried quite a few different ways to solve this. I think the best solution I have come across is to set the width to very small size and it will actually resize/adjust to the larger then assigned width.

Example CSS:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 400px;
    width: 200px; /* just setting it very small it will resize to the input field*/
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Pure CSS and no javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about this plugin: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete.

I ran into the same problem and made a workaround. I set the width as a fixed value like this:

```
$('#input').autocomplete({
    width: 780
});
```

Then whenever the page resizes I run this function:

```
function page_resize(){
    $('.autocomplete-suggestions').css('width', $('#input').width());
}
```