# How to make autocomplete result dropdown responsive using jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have a jquery autocomplete plugin, in which the result dropdown has a specified width.but i am planning to make it responsive. how can i do that?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var autocm = jQuery.noConflict();
    autocm().ready(function() {
      autocm("#search").autocomplete("php/getvalues.php", {
        width: 458,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
      });
    });(autocm);
  </script>
```

Comment: add a `class` to `autocomplete` dropdown and write `media` queries to make it `responsive` or write jquery event on load and assign a `width` based on `window` size

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Autocomplete Plugin 1.2.3 responsive width dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940918/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-1-2-3-responsive-width-dropdown)